# Contact record update trigger

Tags: trigger, custom-field, field-update

I am writing apex trigger. I need help with a salesforce automation.

1. Sets a field "My Field" to Yes. This triggers the code.
2. Code finds all contacts with the same email address.
3. Code updates the field "My Field" to Yes for all these contacts we found in Step 2.

**code:**

```
 trigger stopEmails on Contact (after update) {
      List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>{};
      for (Contact contact : System.Trigger.new)
      {
        if(contact.My_Field__c == 'Yes')
        {
          contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE email = :contact.Email];      
        }   
      }
      for(Contact contact : contacts)
      {
          contact.My_Field__c = 'Yes';
      }
      if(contacts.size() > 0)
      {
          update contacts;
      }
    }
```

Above code not working but i tried my best. someone please help me. i am facing one more problem that is when calling update contacts it again trigger stop Emails so **it become infinite loop**. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few issues that you can avoid..

- SOQL inside loops
- recursive updates

when you look for contacts with the flag, look if its value changed to YES instead of just checking if its value is YES and also avoid updating the same contacts again

```
trigger stopEmails on Contact (after update) {
      List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
      List<String> contactEmails = new List<String>();
      for (Contact contact : Trigger.new)
      {
         Contact oldCon = Trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id);
         if(contact.My_Field__c == 'Yes' && oldCon.My_Field__c != 'Yes')
         {
            contactEmails.add(contact.Email);       
         }   
      }

      contactsToUpdate = [SELECT Id,My_Field__c FROM Contact WHERE email in :contactEmails and Id NOT IN :Trigger.New and My_Field__c != 'Yes'];

      if(contactsToUpdate.size() > 0)
      {
         for(Contact contact : contactsToUpdate )
         {
           contact.My_Field__c = 'Yes';
         }          
         update contactsToUpdate;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Above code not working,  given some error. can you please explain your code especially 'oldCon.Email != "Yes" ' condition. then i can try to clear errors

Comment: tat was suppose to be  oldCon.My_Field__c != 'Yes' .. this condition is to check if your MyField has changed from some other value to YES, then run your logiv.. wat error you are getting ?

Comment: contactsToUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE email in :contactEmails and Id NOT IN Trigger.New];     Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'Trigger.New'

Comment: updated my code.. added another condition to the SOQL to get records with MY Field not equal to Yes, also fixed the syntax issue.

Comment: Thank you very much its working properly. Need explanation for this Contact oldCon = Trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id);

Comment: during an update, Trigger.New will hold the new values and trigger.oldmap will have the old values for the records being updated. You can refer this to understand more https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the contacts in this trigger from your list of contacts.
You can update contacts from an after trigger, but you can't update the contacts that caused this trigger to fire.

So, you need a final loop before updating the contacts:

```
Integer j = 0;
while (j < contacts.size()){
    if(Trigger.newMap.get(j) != null){
        contacts.remove(j);
    }else{
        j++;
    }
}
```

This will remove any contacts that are in your trigger, which hopefully will resolve your issue.

One note - if you were able to provide an idea of why your trigger isn't working, I would be able to give you a better answer, but this is my best guess of what is wrong.

**Note** I see you have added some more details - this solution should prevent the infinite loop issue that you are getting, by not updating the contacts that have just been updated.