# Apex class for trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class, custom-field

I am writing a test class for [Contact record update trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73452/contact-record-update-trigger) I tried my best but it's not working, please check and give suggestion to improve my code

```
@isTest
public class TestStopEmails {
  static testMethod void updateContacts() {
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id = '009O000000aBcdE'];
    for(Contact contact : contacts )
    {
      contact.My_Field__c = 'Yes';
    }
    update contacts;
    contacts = new List<Contact>();
    contacts = [SELECT My_Field__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = '009O000000aBcdF'];
    test.startTest();
    if(contacts.size() > 0)
    {
        System.assert(contacts.get(0).My_Field__c == 'Yes');
    }
    test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should also tell us what exactly is not working and what is the desired result

Comment: If your test is using API 24 or higher then it will not see any data in the org. This means that the SOQL query to get `contacts` will return no results. Your tests should be creating all the records it needs.

Comment: also, hardcoding an ID isn't really a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and insert a dummy contact yourself, test code has no access to [(most)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm) of your org data. This means you can't look up an existing contact by Id like this and your "contacts" list will always be empty.

An extra thing is that you should put Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() around your update call. You can find short description on using these methods [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your help. your answer helped me a lot to complete my task.